# C# XDocument how to use linq to filter elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am reading xml from memorystream using

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(targetStream);

foreach (XElement element in doc.Root.Elements())
{
     Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

one of my element is like below. I am not sure why the namespace xmlns is added to each element. Basically i want to filter all 'Header' elements whose SerialNo = 01

```
<Header xmlns="LR/2020-21">
  <CollectionDetails>
    <Collection>ILR</Collection>
    <Year>2021</Year>
    <FilePreparationDate>2020-05-08</FilePreparationDate>
  </CollectionDetails>
  <Source>
    <ProtectiveMarking>OFFICIAL-SENSITIVE-Personal</ProtectiveMarking>
    <UKPRN>99999999</UKPRN>
    <SoftwareSupplier>SupplierName</SoftwareSupplier>
    <SoftwarePackage>SystemName</SoftwarePackage>
    <Release>1</Release>
    <SerialNo>01</SerialNo>
    <DateTime>2020-05-08T09:14:05</DateTime>
    <!-- This and the next element only appear in files generated by FIS -->
    <ReferenceData>Version5.0, LARS 2018-08-01</ReferenceData>
    <ComponentSetVersion>1</ComponentSetVersion>
  </Source>
</Header>
```

Even the below code bringing empty records

```
        IEnumerable<XElement> list1 =
                            from el in doc.Descendants("Header")
                            where (string)el.Attribute("xmlns") == "LR/2020-21"

                            select el;
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the root-element? Does it have namespace set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to filter on a namespace you need to supply the correct namespace for the element names. Like this:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("LR/2020-21");

var headers = doc.Root
    .Elements(ns + "Header")
    .Where(e => (string)e.Element(ns + "Source").Element(ns + "SerialNo") == "01");
```

If there exist multiple `SerialNo` in the same `Header`-element you can use the following expression.

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("LR/2020-21")

var matchingHeaders = doc.Root
    .Elements(ns + "Header")
    .Where(header => header
        .Elements(ns + "Source")
        .Any(source => source
            .Elements(ns + "SerialNo")
            .Any(serialNo => (string)serialNo == "01")))
```

Comment: why the `.ToList()` at the end?

Comment: Thanks but got another issue if there are multiple <SerialNo> elements in the same <Header>. Can you please help me how to do that?

Comment: @speyck That might not be necessary depending on usage. Sure I'll remove it.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi So are there mulitple SerialNo-elements within the same Source-element or are there multiple Source-elements that each have one SerialNo-element?

Comment: @TorbjörnHansson the actual issue is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67315250/c-sharp-linq-to-xml-filter-elements-whose-any-of-the-children-has-got-a-value

Comment: @MukilDeepthi Added solution for that scenario as well.

Comment: @TorbjörnHansson awesome. thats really great.