# C# linq to xml filter elements whose any of the children has got a value

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I am new to Linq-to-XML. I have the following XML

```
<Message xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="ESFA/ILR/2020-21" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="ESFA/ILR/2020-21">
    <Header xmlns="LR/2020-21">
      <CollectionDetails>
        <Collection>ILR</Collection>
      </CollectionDetails>
      <Source>
        <ProtectiveMarking>OFFICIAL-SENSITIVE-Personal</ProtectiveMarking>
      </Source>
    </Header>
    **<Learner>**
        <LearnRefNumber>LearnerA</LearnRefNumber>
        <PrevLearnRefNumber>123456789</PrevLearnRefNumber>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnStartDate>2020-09-01</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2021-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            **<FundModel>35</FundModel>**
            <DelLocPostCode>NR14 3RR</DelLocPostCode>
        </LearningDelivery>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnStartDate>2020-09-01</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2021-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            **<FundModel>36</FundModel>**
            <DelLocPostCode>NR14 3RR</DelLocPostCode>
        </LearningDelivery>     
    </Learner>
    <Learner>
        <LearnRefNumber>LearnerB</LearnRefNumber>
        <PrevLearnRefNumber>123456789</PrevLearnRefNumber>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnStartDate>2020-09-01</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2021-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            **<FundModel>25</FundModel>**
            <DelLocPostCode>NR14 3RR</DelLocPostCode>
        </LearningDelivery>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnStartDate>2020-09-01</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2021-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            **<FundModel>36</FundModel>**
            <DelLocPostCode>NR14 3RR</DelLocPostCode>
        </LearningDelivery>     
    </Learner>
    <Learner>
        <LearnRefNumber>LearnerC</LearnRefNumber>
        <PrevLearnRefNumber>123456789</PrevLearnRefNumber>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnStartDate>2020-09-01</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2021-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            **<FundModel>35</FundModel>**
            <DelLocPostCode>NR14 3RR</DelLocPostCode>
        </LearningDelivery>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnStartDate>2020-09-01</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2021-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            **<FundModel>26</FundModel>**
            <DelLocPostCode>NR14 3RR</DelLocPostCode>
        </LearningDelivery>     
    </Learner>
</Message>
```

I want to filter only the learner who have got LearningDelivery element with FundModel = 36. So in the below example, i am expecting LearnerA and B.

I tried below:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(targetStream);
    var ns = XNamespace.Get(xmlNameSpace);
    var learners = doc.Root.Elements(ns + "Learner")
        .Where(e => (string)e.Element(ns + "LearningDelivery").Element(ns + "FundModel") == "36")
        .ToList();
```

But getting 0 records. Can anyone please help with this?

Thanks

Comment: Got solved in other thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67314656/c-sharp-xdocument-how-to-use-linq-to-filter-elements/67314818?noredirect=1#67314818

Comment: @dbc yes, i got the answer from the above link